# email the Infopath form and update in sharepoint library

Tags: infopath

1st Query: 
I am working on Infopath 2007 and sharepoint 2010. I have created a form in Infopath designer.I have created a submit button on the form. The submit button is programmed to submit the form to a sharepint library. That was successful. However what i want to do now is submit the form to a sharepoint library and also send an email with the attached form to email recipients. Is that possible?
2nd Query:
I have included contact selector in my form and it works fine to pull the name from company directory. I have linked the contact selector to sharepoint(I created the.xml file to get this established). I have 3 attributes to the contact selector `DisplayName`, `AccountID` and `AccountType`. I am guessing out of these 3 attributes AccountID picks up the email address. But when I try to retrieve information from `AccountID` it gives me  group/username and not the email address. So when I try to submit the form to this `AccountID` it does not happen.

Answer (score 2):

Query 1:

You have a couple of options for this:

1. Once the form has been submitted, you can use either SharePoint designer or Nintex Workflow to send email
2. if you do not mind using InfoPath form with Code behind then it can be done

Query 2:

You again have a couple of options:

1. Use the getUserProfileByName web service to get the user profile. Then on form load set a fields value by filtering the email address using this in filter data Value[Name = "WorkEmail"] [image: Check the image]
2. You can use workflow again to send an email to the user who has submitted the request

Hope it helps :)